# Is there a way to restore missing package.json?

Tags: npm, node-modules

I'm working on react projects, then i want to upload it to github pages, so i follow some tutorials, and there are steps to install gh-pages via npm. So i install it, but i terminate the process by pressing `ctrl+c`, and it stop the process. And i feel i have to uninstall it, so i do `npm uninstall gh-pages --save-dev`. The process isn't finished, and my laptop overheat and died (old laptop sorry).

And i went back, i want to check the packages. After running `npm list --depth=0`, its showing so much extraneous error, no such file directory and and path ended with package.json. My package.json on each modules missing, i've been checked it, only left 1 package.json on root folder.

[image]
[image]

and much more error messages

Is there a way to get it back all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run commands sequentially:

- `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
- `npm i`

Then if you want to install that package again, run

- `npm i gh-pages`

Comment: is rm -rf equivalent with rmdir /s? im using windows btw